# how to set break point in specific file using 'perl -d'

Tags: perl, debugging, package

### I used the following command to debug program.

perl -d -I "./Dev/lib/" -I "./TestCases/Dev/" ./Dev/bin/mytest.pl

I want to use 'perl -d ' to debug mytest.pl, and there are many *.pm files. I want to  use 'f *.pm' to load this pm file and set a break in this pm file, but it shows 'No file matching'. I give the full path of this pm file and the path exactly exists.

```
DB<4> f /automation_code/TestCases/Tests/Dev/testcase1.pm

No file matching '/automation_code/TestCases/Tests/Dev/testcase1.pm' is loaded.
```

But if i give the path composed by ./Dev/bin, it will be loaded successfully.

```
DB<2> f /automation_code/Dev/bin/../lib/Setup.pm



DB<3> f /automation_code/Dev/lib/Setup.pm

No file matching '/automation_code/Dev/lib/Setup.pm' is loaded.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see all the files loaded into your program with the command

```
x values %INC
```

**Edit**

the b command in the debugger takes several options.

- `b load *filename*` breaks when the file is loaded
- `b compile *subname*` breaks when the subroutine is compiled
- `b postpone *subname*` will put a breakpoint on a subroutine that doesn't currently exist.

Comment: Yes, i can see all the loaded files, but has no any files i concerned. All pm files i concerned will be loaded when execution, but the call stack is very complex.  If there is a simple way to set break point in my concerned files?

Comment: winnie, `f ...` only works with files that have already been loaded and compiled, either visible in `%INC` or in the keys that start with `_<` in the `main::` stash (`x grep/^_</,keys %main::`). If your script loads files at runtime, you can't use `f ...` with those files until after they have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks. So it is difficult for me to debug these pm files. Or if i can add debug code in pm files like python?

Comment: You can set `$DB::single = 1` inside the files to set a break point, even in compile-time code.

Comment: It works when i only add one break point. But if i added several $DB::Single = 1 into two pm files, only one $DB::Single = 1 works, the related code of other non-work $DB::Single is exactly executed.

Answer (score 2):

If your framework is trying to emulate the Object oriented approach and the perl file is used as package, then you can try below option:

```
DB<1> use <package_name_of_file>
DB<2> b <package_name_of_file>::sub_routine_where_you_want_to_break
```

It worked for me when `b postpone` and `f <file_name>` were not working to debug a routine which was going to be loaded at much later point in time.